# find the volume using disks/washers and cylindrical shells

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the volume of the solid of revolution obtained by rotating the region bounded by $x=1-y^2$, $y=-x-1$, and the x-axis about the vertical line $x=1$ using:

- a) disks/washers
- b) cylindrical shells

Comment: What have you tried?  (This is not a site for "Here's my problem... solve it for me."

Comment: my concern is i'm not sure wheter i would add +1 to the radius terms (outer and inner)

Comment: also i'm not sure for the radius terms using the cylindrical shells method (should i add +1)

Comment: Add your attempt to your question so we can see.  We can correct you if you're going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

a) For integrating with disks, just measure radii along each disk

> which are $(1-(1-y^2))=y^2$ and $1-(-y-1)=2+y$

b) Integrating with shells just need the height of shells

> which are $\sqrt{1-x}-(-x-1) $ over some range and $2\sqrt{1-x}$ over some range

Comment: I like also the ghost code :-)